# What AWS ec2 instance to choose for getting 20 GB of storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to use an AWS ec2 instance just to compile a very large project. I won't use it for anything else. The project should be about 20 GB in size. Its not clear to be how to choose an instance. I've already tried t2 small (before I knew how big the package would be), and then I tried a t2 xlarge, which is still too small. Is there clear documentation on what instance will meet my memory needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage on EC2 instances is elastic, this applies for all the instance types.

The instance type (t2.small for example) only sets the CPU, memory and bandwidth, but the storage is set after you choose the instance type. The proper name for it is EBS Volumes (Elastic Block Storage Volumes). Storage is pretty cheap so you can create an instance with I'd say 30 GB in size.

You can find more info here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html

Comment: So I could launch a t2 (of any size), and add 30 GiB during the 'add storage' portion on the console and it would meet my needs?

Answer (score 0):

If 20gb of storage (20gb storage != 20gb memory), you can either find an instance with a min of 20gb of ephemeral storage attached to it or find any instance and attach a 20gb ebs volume. Some instances come with ephemeral storage attached, others assume that you will attach ebs volumes for storage. For instances with a min of 20gb ephemeral storage, [this](https://instances.vantage.sh/?min_storage=20). is a useful tool that filters that for you. If you want 20gb of memory, you can filter by memory using that same tool.